# jQuery Is there a way to wait for object to load before continuing?

Tags: jquery

I have a problem relating to cookies.
I have a group of buttons that display a specific table related to the button pushed. I have it setup to assign cookie values and I'm trying to get it to remember what was last viewed so users don't have to reselect everything every time they close the page.

```
if($.cookie('lastviewed') == "value") {
   $('#Button1').trigger('click');
   $('#Button2').trigger('click');
}
```

Button 1 Loads in Button 2, so the above doesn't work because its trying to trigger something that doesn't exist yet.

Is there a way to make it wait for it to load before continuing?

Edit: I am already using document.ready.
Clicking button 1 loads button 2 onto the page, I need it to wait for it to finish loading in button 2 before it tries to click it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna try this too:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($.cookie('lastviewed') == "value") {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#Button1').trigger('click');
            $('#Button2').trigger('click');
        }, 100);
    }
});
```

After a delay of 100ms, this will cause the click event after all the $(document).ready() handlers have been called.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to ensure the html elements are available before they are being accessed by javascript/jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($.cookie('lastviewed') == "#value") {
     $('#Button1').trigger('click');
     $('#Button2').trigger('click');
  }    
});
```

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a
>   page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets
>   such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the
>   script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully
>   constructed. The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be
>   executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to
>   attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code. [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: I'm already using document.ready.
Button 2 will not load in until after Button 1 has been clicked, so at the time, it's trying to click both when Button 2 doesn't exist yet.